# how to pass echo statement output as argument to function?

Tags: shell-script, function

I just want to pass the echo statement output as argument(`${1}`) to the logger function in the following example:

```
logfile=./testlog

`touch ${logfile}`

function logger(){
  echo "[${USER}] [$nowTimestamp] [INFO] ${1}" >> ${logfile}
}

echo "started executing script" | logger
```

Comment: logger "started executing script"

Comment: Insider logger function replace $1 to  $@

Comment: my actual intention is to log the all echo statements output in a large shell script to logfile by calling this function. so in every call of this funciton can't write like (logger "started executing script")....

Answer (score 1):

Aside: `logger` is a standard Unix (POSIX) utility. You might choose a different name to avoid confusion.

For a *program* you could use `| xargs -d '\n' logger`. This would include the case where you rewrite your function as a script file, with 'shebang' line if necessary; however getting all the correct environment to that script could be difficult.

For a function, the only way to pass an argument is to pass an argument. You could write a second function that wraps your first function, which I'll rename `logger1`:

```
logger1(){ echo "... $1" >>$file; }
logger2(){ read -r x; logger1 "$x"; }

echo this is some log info | logger2
```

or you could just have your function `read` its input in the first place. You could even code a loop and have it handle multiple lines if provided, like the real logging facilities in most systems do.

Answer (score 0):

put the echo statement inside the function.

```
logfile=./testlog

`touch ${logfile}`

function logger()
{
echo "$@"
echo "[${USER}] [$nowTimestamp] [INFO] ${1}" >> ${logfile}

}

logger "started executing scirpt"
```

Comment: thanks,its working fine... But is there anyway to automatically redirect the output of echo statement as argument of this function like i have given using "|" ? please suggest..

Comment: Try `logger <(echo "started executing script)`

Comment: it's not working....

Comment: its is working logger `echo "started executing script"`